# Does an instance of this generalisation of the determinant exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinants

Let $n$ be composite, $d$ a divisor greater than $1$ and $m=n/d$. Does anybody know if there is a general mapping $T$ from $n×n$ matrices to $m×m$ matrices that preserves the determinant? Over a field you can choose?

In such a way that the entries of $T(A)$ degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials in the entries of $A$?

Or do we need to take a subalgebra of the $n×n$ matrices for this?

Any example $(n,d,T)$ and field is welcome.

Comment: For instance, view A as a block matrix with $m\times m$ blocks, each block being a $d\times d$ matrix. Then take the determinant of each block.

Comment: Does that work? Is the determinant over all the $d×d$ matrices and after that on the resulting $m×m$ matrix the total determinant of the $n×n$ matrix?

Comment: That doesn't work. For $m=d=2$ the permutation $(1 2 3 4)$ does not come in the resulting sum.

Comment: Wouldn't $T(A)=\mathrm{diag}(1,\ldots,1,\det(A))$ do the job? (Except for the homogeneous polynomials bit, but you said "preferably").

Comment: I'll remove the preferably ;)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully. I missed that you want it to preserve the determinant.